# how to iterate through 1 min OHLC to get MA values of different timeframe

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve the following:

input data is in 1 min OHLC format 1.

1. if price of 15 min candle is closed above 9MA, 18MA and 25MA
2. if all MA are in order, i.e., 9 MA is above 18MA and 18MA is above 25 MA in 15min time frame.
   if above two condition is true, check
3. if next 2 min OHLC candle is closed above 9MA, 18MA and 25MA
4. check if all MA are in order, i.e., 9 MA is above 18MA and 18MA is above 25 MA in 2min time frame.
   if all of the above 4 conditions are true:
5. if any next 5 min OHLC candle low is below 9 MA but closed above 9 MA
6. If all of above conditions are true, check if any 5 mins OHLC candle is
   crossing high of any red candle.

buy above that candle

```
data_15min = data.resample('15T').agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
data_15min['EMA9'] = data_15min['Close'].ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean()
data_15min['EMA18'] = data_15min['Close'].ewm(span=18, adjust=False).mean()
data_15min['EMA25'] = data_15min['Close'].ewm(span=25, adjust=False).mean()

data_2min = data.resample('2T').agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
data_2min['EMA9'] = data_2min['Close'].ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean()
data_2min['EMA18'] = data_2min['Close'].ewm(span=18, adjust=False).mean()
data_2min['EMA25'] = data_2min['Close'].ewm(span=25, adjust=False).mean()

data_5min = data.resample('5T').agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
data_5min['EMA9'] = data_5min['Close'].ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean()
data_5min['EMA18'] = data_5min['Close'].ewm(span=18, adjust=False).mean()
data_5min['EMA25'] = data_5min['Close'].ewm(span=25, adjust=False).mean()

for i in range(len(data_15min)):
    if data_15min.iloc[i]['Close'] > data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA9'] and data_15min.iloc[i]['Close'] > data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA18'] and data_15min.iloc[i]['Close'] > data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA25']:
        if data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA9'] > data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA18'] > data_15min.iloc[i]['EMA25']:
            if i+1 < len(data_2min):
                if data_2min.iloc[i+1]['Close'] > data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA9'] and data_2min.iloc[i+1]['Close'] > data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA18'] and data_2min.iloc[i+1]['Close'] > data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA25']:
                    if data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA9'] > data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA18'] and data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA18'] > data_2min.iloc[i+1]['EMA25']:
                        if i+3 < len(data_5min):
                            if data_5min.iloc[i + 3]['Low'] < data_5min.iloc[i + 3]['EMA9']:
                                for j in range(i+3, len(data_5min)):
                                    if data_5min.iloc[j]['Close'] > data_5min.iloc[j-1]['High'] and data_5min.iloc[j-1]['Close'] < data_5min.iloc[j-1]['Open']:
                                        print(f"Buy above {data_5min.iloc[j]['High']}")
                                        break
                                break
```

Although i can see in chart that conditions are fulfilled, but i am getting no output. what am i doing wrong?

sample data:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
24-02-2023 09:15:00,40259.1,40259.1,40160.15,40206.6
24-02-2023 09:16:00,40208.95,40209.4,40173.3,40178.15
24-02-2023 09:17:00,40177.3,40178.95,40116.55,40178.95
24-02-2023 09:18:00,40176.65,40210.05,40176.65,40186.85
24-02-2023 09:19:00,40187.55,40219.2,40157.35,40218.35
24-02-2023 09:20:00,40217.5,40254.25,40215.7,40237.55
```